# set the value null before entering into a condition

Tags: reactjs

I want to clear a value when backspace or null value clicked. The first selected value is set always when we click backspace

```
 onValueChange(e,value)
    {  
        if(e.target === undefined){
        this.setState({value:e});
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({value:e.target.value})
        }

        const { patientsMasterData, addPatientForm } = this.props;
        let selectedRefValue = patientsMasterData.ReferredBy.filter(o=> o.RefName === (value.options));
        if(selectedRefValue.length !== 0) {

            addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy = selectedRefValue[0].RefID;
        }
        else{
            addPatientForm.values.ReferredBy = null;
        }
    }
```

How to set the value first as null?